# I fail to access my elementor page editor when I click on "edit with elementor"

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using localhost on my PC to Build Websites locally. And when I want to edit any page with elementor by clicking on "edit with elementor", it throws me this error. "cURL error 6: could not resolve host: my elementor." How do I resolve it? My xampp server is active with MySQL & Apache all turned on. I have been smoothly running this service for about 2 months now.

I have tried to change max_execution_time under the phpini file. I also deactivated all other plugins and reactivated one at a time. I updated the theme as well changed the theme to the default theme. All futile